# Codeigniter Validation Not Working When Uploading Multiple Images Using Single Input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload multiple images in codeigniter using single input its working fine but i also want to add codeigniter validation on this input field but it not works.
Here's my html code,

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="file" multiple="">
```

And Here's my codeigniter Code,

```
if (empty($_FILES['images']['name']))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('images', 'Item Image', 'required');
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this validation not working when i try to change images name to images[] in codeigniter then this will always says image is required rather the image is selected.

Comment: This works for me: <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="pic[]" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg"/>

Comment: please refer this link [https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-file-upload-validation/]

Comment: not working for me, can you show me your controller code for validation ?

Comment: should be `if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name']))`, right?

Comment: yeah but that's not works.

Comment: Try this `$this->form_validation->set_rules('images', 'images', 'required', array('required' => 'Image is required.'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the validation function yourself using callback:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('file', '', 'callback_file_check');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            // Upload
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('upload');
}

public function file_check($str)
{
    $allowed_mime_type_arr = array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/png');
    $mime = get_mime_by_extension($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES['file']['name']!="")
    {
        if(in_array($mime, $allowed_mime_type_arr))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('file_check', 'Please select only gif/jpg/png file.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('file_check', 'Please choose a file to upload.');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: @IkramKhizer, i tested it and it is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply validation on the count of `$_FILES['images']['name']`.

```
if (count($_FILES['images']['name']) < 1)
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('images', 'Item Image', 'required');
}
```

Comment: @IkramKhizer are you getting the count value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if (count($_FILES['images']['name']) == 0)
{
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('images', 'Item Image', 'required');
}
```

Comment: <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images[]" multiple="">

Comment: change id in the input tag

Comment: Use the above input tag that I mentioned in the comment

Comment: add this code  in form tag:   enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: like this <form  action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/xxxx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 0):

Your input name is **name="images[]"**
So try this one...

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('images[]', 'Item Image', 'required');
```

So you can call form validation when you have no files on POST.

```
if(count($_FILES['images']['name']) < 1) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('images[]', 'Item Image', 'required');
}else {
   // upload files
}
```

Comment: not works in this case if i upload an image then it still says the image field is required.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean call form validation when you have no files on POST